# regex to match only double NOT int

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression that matches only double numbers and doesn't match integers at the same time. The double number can be either positive or negative and can also look like this: .99

Now I have this: `^(-?(\d+)?.\d+)$`
Although it still matches itntegers. Maybe anyone can help?

I'm thinking of checking sth like this:

```
if('regexForIntegersOnly' && matches("^(-?(\d+)?.\d+)$"))
```

But maybe there's a way to do it with just one regex?

Comment: I'm seeing that you've posted requirements, but I don't see any focused and specific questions just yet. In other words, you're posting "needs", not questions. So what have you done? Where exactly are you stuck? How does your current attempt not work? Please have a look at the [help] for more information on how to improve your question and increase your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you NEED this... what are YOU going to do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dot `.` is metacharacter in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) representing any character (except line separators). To make it match only `.` literal you need to escape it. Try with

```
^(-?(\d+)?\.\d+)$
          ^-escaped dot
```